when "inline tooltip" wraps into the second line the tooltip content doesn't seem to be positioned properly
I have a code where you can hover over the italicized text to reveal a tooltip. the tooltip content works well when inline tooltip has just one line.

video: https://imgur.com/a/ioTrWag
But the problem occurs when inline tooltip has more than one line.

video: https://imgur.com/a/GxkS7BC
Is it possible to make the tooltip content appears below the part of "inline tooltip"? because it seems to appear incorrectly.
basically, I am aiming for something like this (also courtesy to Wikipedia)
https://imgur.com/a/vnmbsnU


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const tooltipContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip-container');

    tooltipContainers.forEach(container => {
        const tooltipText = container.querySelector('.tooltip-text');
        
        container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
            const rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
            const xPos = event.clientX - rect.left;
            const leftPercentage = (xPos / rect.width) * 100;
            tooltipText.style.left = `${leftPercentage}%`;
            tooltipText.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
            tooltipText.style.visibility = 'visible';
            tooltipText.style.opacity = '1';
        });

        container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
            tooltipText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            tooltipText.style.opacity = '0';
            tooltipText.style.left = '50%';
        });
    });
});
.tooltip-container {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: calc(100% + 8px);
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    white-space: normal;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #555;
}

.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip-text {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, laudantium! 
    <span class="tooltip-container">
        <i>"inline tooltip"</i> <span class="tooltip-text">This is the tooltip content. It will appear below the inline text.</span>
    </span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, laudantium! 
</p>




In your sample image tooltip is already below second line. I think you mean end of second line ?

Could you clarify exactly where the tooltip is to be in each of the two cases. At the moment it’s positioned half way along when the text is all on one line. Do you want that to change to it pointing to the end of the text in this case too?

@AHaworth, Sorry for unclear post. I'm trying to make the tooltip content appears below at the middle of the lasted line of the inline text like what it does when the text is all on one line but it seems like the tooltip keeps appearing incorrectly below the empty space when the inline text has multiple lines.

@Meet, yes, the tooltip is already below the second line but the tooltip content is supposed to be under the middle of the text on the second line but somehow it got pushed to the right.

It's 2024 now so you can use Anchored Positions: see https://developer.chrome.com/blog/anchor-positioning-api and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_anchor_positioning

This is the expected behaviour. The positioning is based on the original size of the container. the parent container doesn't know when its children wrap. Hence, it continues changing its size oblivious to what's going on inside. Put another way, the browser renders the container on the initial cascade. It doesn't reflow the document when a child wraps.

@Dai, Thank you, I'll give it a try

@Paulie_D, thank you for your comment, so what's the best solution to fix this?

the only solution I've found so far is changing from display: inline; to display: inline-block; but it isn't what i've been looking for

The suggestion from Dai would seem to be ideal.

For a general solution that works on most browser's today you may need JavaScript for this, and it's a bit messy. Is JS acceptable? Also, where do you want the tooltip if there is only a tiny bit of text on the last line?

@AHaworth, Yes, Anything is acceptable but i have little to no knowledge of using JS. is it possible to make the tooltip appears below at the middle of the text on the last line? Thanks for your help. https://imgur.com/MkaWDe8

We'd need to know what is to happen if that would result in the tooltip being outside the viewport. It gets a bit messy as I said, have you considered using the inbuilt action on hover if the element has a title instead of creating your own tooltip?

@AHaworth, so the best way to fix this is either using "Anchored Positions" or "Prebuilt tooltip", right?

I don't know enough about anchored positions to help on that, but I think they may not be completely implemented on all browsers at the moment - check on caniuse.com before using a particular feature.

To get tooltip text centered on the last line you need to define the width of the last line, using the span tag, as in my example. Also, note that in the tss I redefined .tooltip-container as p, which will position your tooltip text strictly centered.


let p = document.querySelector('p'),
    tooltipText = document.querySelector('.tooltip-text');
p.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span class="determiner"></span>')
tooltipText.style.left = `${document.querySelector('.determiner').offsetLeft / 2}px`
p {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: calc(100% + 8px);
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    display: block;
    white-space: normal;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #555;
}

.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip-text {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
<p>
    Here is some text with an
    <span class="tooltip-container">
        <i>"inline tooltip" wraps into the second line the tooltip content doesn't seem to be positioned properly (like this)</i> <span class="tooltip-text">This is the tooltip content. It will appear below the inline text.</span>
    </span>
    ?
</p>




This doesn't work - different viewports etc cause the tooltip to be in different (relative) places - which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

@AHaworth, It works the first time you run it. Try reducing the size, and run the snippet again. Yes, i need to add the resize event, but this is a quick solution. If the OP asks me to fix it, I will add it to event resize.

@s.kuznetsov I appreciate your help, it works well in snippet but for me it works like in the video: https://imgur.com/a/4DoMidN
basically, I am aiming for something like this (also courtesy to Wikipedia)
https://imgur.com/a/vnmbsnU
